# How to display images saved in a private folder of an Asp.Net Core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

### ContentRootPath

I have changed the `ContentRootPath` to `c:\images` as follows.

```
public class Program
{
    // others are removed for simplicity.

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseContentRoot(@"c:\images")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

There are only JPEG photos in `c:\images`.

### Controller

Using DI, I can access `ContentRootPath` via `_env` as follows.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string crp = _env.ContentRootPath;
        object[] filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(crp)
            .Select(x=>Path.GetFileName(x))
            .ToArray<string>();

        return View(filepaths);

    }


    [HttpGet]
    public FileStreamResult ViewImage(string filename)
    {
        string filepath = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, filename);

        byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

### CSHTML

```
@model IList<object> 


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <img src="/Home/ViewImage/@item" />
}
```

### Problem and Question

`filename` is always `null`.  What is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at, and verify the result of `Directory.GetFiles(crp)`?

Comment: Do you get any errors?  Check out this post and see if it helps at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473811/mvc-how-to-serve-images-to-response-stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using (presumably) a default routing, your last routing parameter is `id` and optional.

To make your `get` work, you can alter your image source to a route with a named parameter:

```
<img src="/Home/ViewImage?filename=@item" />
```